# Automatically close RegSvr32 prompts

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, command-line, regsvr32

I have a C# program that executes some batch files which invoke RegSvr32. When it executes some prompts appear like "Something completed successfully" with "OK" button. How can I automatically close them (so that user won't see them)?

It is a console application. I don't want to reference Forms or libraries like this to imitate keypress.

A screenshot:
[image: BatMessage]

Comment: *Some batch files*, bat-files? You want to close console window after executing bat-file? Could you show screenshot?

Comment: @Sinatr yep, .bat files. Added screenshot to my post. I execute many regSvr commands, so many windows appear and that is no good for user

Comment: You can run [RegSvr32](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx) silently with the /s flag.

Comment: @mikez mike! thank you much, that worked! Can you, please, make a post, so i could mark at as answer?

Answer (score 4):

You can run [RegSvr32](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx) silently with the /s flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim Procinfo As New ProcessStartInfo(<<Batch File Path>>) With {.RedirectStandardOutput = True, .RedirectStandardError = True, .UseShellExecute = False, .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden, .CreateNoWindow = True}
 Dim Proc As Process = Process.Start(Procinfo)
```

With properties ***WindowStyle*** and ***CreateNoWindow*** you can hide the command line window. Also you can handle the batch execution state from ***Proc*** object.

```
 Dim sOut As StreamReader = Proc.StandardOutput
 Dim sError As StreamReader = Proc.StandardError
 Dim Outputs As String = sOut.ReadToEnd
 Dim Errors As String = sError.ReadToEnd
```

Comment: this wont help with messageBoxes, created by cmd. I use similar code to execute my batches.